# python string literals 'r prefix at run-time'

Tags: python

What is the most elegant method to get the functionality
of the r-prefix on string literals at run-time. That is,
a string is constructed dynamically

```
 my_re_str = somefunction()
```

and then, all the backslashes need to be put back in place
whenever there is a '\n', '\b' and the like. The reason
for this is that the string is used to compile a regular
expression in the form of

```
 my_re = re.compile(my_re_str)
```

where with constant string literals one might write

```
 my_re = re.compile(r"something")
```

Is there an elegant method to achieve this without manually
replacing all backslash-ed characters?

Comment: The "r" is only used by the compiler to handle escape rules for strings typed in by us humans. There shouldn't be any need to use it on programaticly constructed strings.

Comment: `my_re_str.encode('unicode-escape')` does what you're asking, but I don't think it does what you actually need: actual control characters in a regex aren't a problem, and there are other characters that need to be escaped if meant literally.  You might also want to look at `re.escape()`.

Comment: @jasonharper: That is what I was looking for! Thanks. I do not know whether the editors actually read the question. I could not find any other question on this account and why it was marked 'duplicate'.